# Fastest way to turn large pandas dataframe in a dictionary with a specific structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-structures

I have a large dataframe with about 40 million rows, structured this way:

```
    author    video

0  "user1"   "video1"
1  "user2"   "video1"
2  "user2"   "video2"
3  "user3"   "video3"
```

Where the author field refers to the author of comments under specific videos.
Also please notice how the "authors" are not unique values.

What I'd like to do would be reorganizing this dataframe in a data structure for which, to each author, a list containing all of the video under which they commented is assigned. I was thinking of something like this:

```
  {"user1": ["video1"],

  "user2": ["video1", "video2"], 

  "user3": ["video3"]}
```

I tried using a for loop that, for each (precomputed) unique value in the author field, computes a new dataframe such as:

`new_df = df[(df["author"] == name_of_the_author)]`

So that then, from this new dataframe, I could build the list of videos under which a single author comments, but this takes several seconds for each iteration, which is truly awful since I have almost 4 million unique authors

I'm sure there is an easier and faster way to do this, but I couldn't find a solution

Thank you in advance to everyone who might help me or point me in the right direction!

Comment: Aggregating as lists will probably be slow no matter what method is used. Are your authors sorted? How many authors do you have?

Comment: No, the authors aren't sorted, and there are about 4 million unique authors for a total of around 40 million rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df.groupby('author')['video'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Or maybe in pure python:

```
out = {}

for author, video in zip(df['author'], df['video']):
    out.setdefault(author, []).append(video)
```

Output:

```
{'user1': ['video1'], 'user2': ['video1', 'video2'], 'user3': ['video3']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much: It only took 3 minutes!